# How to do Million level Dictionary Search **(Non-English)**

Tags: c, file, dictionary, search

There is a dictionary csv file, **million level data & not English(Chinese or Japanese for example)**, the biggest word is up to **32bytes**

Everytime I want to search word in the file.

Now my solution is **Block Search**:

1. First sort the data
2. Then and I split N datas into Sqrt(N) Blocks and get **file offset** of the first data in every Blocks using **ftell in C**, then store them in a Index file in this way: (word), (offset in dict)
3. Every time I get a word search request, I **open the Index file and read line one by one** until I find that this word is in this Block, then I use **fseek to relocate to that block's first data at the dict file, and then read line one by one** until I find the data in the dict.

Is this solution appropriate or is there any space to improve?
Or is there any other solutions? I don't know how to use hash or tree to search data in a file. Do I have to remake them at request?
Thanks!!!!!

Comment: What is your goal?  Faster search?  Less memory?  You may want to look into [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: @TheGreatContini is it too large for Chinese? There are over 20000 chinese characters in unicode, emm ms level of search and usage of memory is as small as possible?

Comment: @ENEKaIku One million 32-byte words is tiny in most modern environments. As TheGreatContini asked, what are you trying to achieve?
 You need to do some research on simple search data structures.  It's easily possible to build a trie for an arbitrarily large alphabet by hashing the edge labels. With a trie constructed in this manner, looking up a word of N characters requires time proportional to N with a very small constant factor. The size of the dictionary doesn't matter. If you don't like tries, then simple hash tables and binary search trees will both do much better than your algorithm.

Comment: Your approach isn't bad at all. My first thought would be to use a simple array with the number of elements equal to the number of characters in the language you are using (I have no idea how many that is for Chinese or Japanese). For each element, you could store the beginning offset as you are doing. You would know the size of each block by subtracting the offset in `array[x+1] - array[x]` for example. You could then use the first char in the word to identify the block and read it into memory for searching (you could delay `free` until next search and check to reuse the current block).

Comment: @Gene Thanks! But how to store the trie or hash tables? Is it the same as block search, I have to get the file offset as "pointer" and store it into another file?

Comment: Got it!!!! Thank all of you so much!!!!

Comment: It's likely there are _many_ better algorithms than the one you've proposed. But we can't say because you still haven't explained your goals. If you're doing many lookups, then you should _read all the data into an efficient search structure in memory_, not mess around with direct access through byte offsets in files.  The only reason to avoid an in-memory structure is that your environment is so constrained that ~50Mb for a search structure is too much memory. We can't answer your question if you don't explain what you need. Voting to close because the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought on this is that a million is not a big number for this sort of data set size. Using a basic balanced binary search should be log2(million) compares, or about 20 compares per search. Keeping it as simple as possible, I would read the 32-byte keys into an array of structures that contain (key, file offset):

```
struct record {
  uint8_t key[32];
  uint8_t key_length;
  uint64_t file_offset;
};

#define MAX_RECORDS 1000000

struct record my_index[MAX_RECORDS];
```

Then ensure that 'my_index' array is sorted by key, which can be simply accomplished using the standard libraries qsort() function (https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort). Once that is done, you may implement a divide-and-conquer binary array search following the algorithm laid out here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm ... This algorithm is implemented by the standard C library's bsearch() function (https://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch).

Comment: Thanks! But how to store this? I mean if I want to use this record every time, then do I have to load this from file into memory?

Comment: You would read & parse your file, storing nothing but the keys & offsets in the array-of-structures I mentioned previously... From there, retrieving the record data would be an open/seek/read sequence, or getting fancier, you could also mmap() the file region referenced by the offset.

Comment: ... you could conceivably also write your index array out to a separate file as well that you could load/update/store as binary data. The old dbm/ndbm/gdbm file-backed databases did something very similar.